# High-order continuous Galerkin Navier-Stokes solver in deal.II

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I looked at the list of publications related to deal.II, but it seems that when it comes to Navier-Stokes equations, everyone speaks about Discontinuous Galerkin solver in their papers. I know there's also a Continuous Galerkin method implemented in deal.II. Has it been used for high-order accurate solution of Navier-Stokes equations? Could someone comment on performance/accuracy differences between CG and DG for fluid flow problems in deal.II?

Comment: This is a problem probably better asked on the deal.II mailing list.